# fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_attributes() must be of the type array, string given, called in theme.inc on line 1714

Tags: 7, theming

i am registering themes using hook_theme in mymodule, following is code of my hook

```
function mymodule_theme() {
    return array(
        'updates' => array(
          'template' => 'templates/updates',
        ),
        'links' => array(
          'template' => 'templates/links',
        ),
    );
}
```

Following error occur

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_attributes() must
>   be of the type array, string given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bnsp\includes\theme.inc on line 1714 and defined in
>   drupal_attributes() (line 2371 of
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bnsp\includes\common.inc).

is there any error??

Comment: Your error is not coming from the code you are showing. It's somewhere else altogether.